# using a datepicker with meteor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I've been trying for a day to get a datepicker working in my meteor app. There are a few questions here about this but none of them seem to provide a full answer. I finally got one installed without causing errors by following this-

> OK, I got this working manually using bootstrap-datepicker.js and datepicker.css from http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ and dropping these files into the client folder. Used the markup as mentioned in that page along with the following template helper:

```
Template.templatename.rendered = function() {
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
}
```

No matter what info I put in my template I couldn't get it working so I tried this answer for the template helper-

```
    Template.datepicker.events ({           
         'focus #datepicker': function () {
              $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                format: 'M dd, yyyy',
                autoclose: true
               })
            console.log('#datepicker has focus');
         }
    });
```

Still nothing but a blank input field. This is my current html template-

```
<template name="datepicker">
        <div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
        <input id="datepicker" class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>

</template>
```

I suspect that my only problem is understanding what it is that datepicker is returning to the template.

Comment: Did you change `Template.templatename.rendered` to `Template.datepicker.rendered` ?

Comment: Adam, yes I did. Any idea what I could put in the console to see what info $('#datepicker').datepicker() throws out?

Comment: The problem appears to be no class="icon-th" exists so no image exists to click. Still trying to figure out how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you never tell the datepicker to 'show'. You're putting initialization code inside of the 'focus' event where you should be telling it to show. For example, try:

```
Template.datepicker.rendered = function() {
  // initialize datepicker
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'm, dd, yyyy'
  });
};

Template.datepicker.events ({           
  'focus #datepicker': function () {
    // show datepicker
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('show');  
    console.log('#datepicker has focus');
  }
});
```

Alternatively, this [datetimepicker package](https://atmospherejs.com/tsega/bootstrap3-datetimepicker) works well for me.

Comment: Your code worked after I found and installed bootstrap.css. Only it doesn't auto close and the date appears as dd yyyy Apparently I don't have bootstrap. I thought that was included with meteor?

Comment: Glad you got it working! Meteor doesn't come with bootstrap, although adding it is only a matter of one line (meteor add ...). Keep in mind that Meteor's bootstrap package isn't yet v3, so if you want bootstrap 3 you should go with one of the atmosphere packages.

Comment: I overlooked your other question, sorry. Try changing the format to 'm, dd, yyyy'. Looks like this datepicker doesn't have autoclose, so you could try using the .on('changeDate') and call 'hide' from there

Comment: I'm going to install bootstrap 3 and go with the one you suggested. bootstrap blew up all my css anyway so might as go ahead and do that.

Comment: I installed bootstrap 3 for meteor 9.* and then bootstrap3-datetimepicker. I used the sample code provided but my datepicker appears outside the <div> that contains {{> datepicker}}, in fact it appears outside of everything at the end of the page but the <input> field appears in the correct place?.